# find out which file in program contains "main" using makefile

Tags: makefile, wildcard, program-entry-point

I'm trying to do something tricky over here.

Currently, my makefile naming the executable as the parent directory, which is nice. But I would like to improve it. For example, I got few files in `/home/Daniel/project1/**files here**`, the executable will be named `project1`

Let's say I got 10 files in the directory, and only one of them, "main.c" got the main function - I want makefile to name the executable "main".

Here is my current makefile:

```
# Declaration of variables
COMPILE = gcc -m32 -g -ansi -Wall -c
COMPILE_ASM = nasm -g -f elf -w+all
LINK = gcc -m32 -g -Wall -o

# File names
EXEC = $(notdir $(shell pwd))
SOURCES_C = $(wildcard *.c)
SOURCES_ASM = $(wildcard *.s)
OBJECTS = $(SOURCES_C:.c=.o) $(SOURCES_ASM:.s=.o)

all: clean $(EXEC)

# Main target
$(EXEC): $(OBJECTS)
    $(LINK) $(EXEC) $(OBJECTS)

# To obtain object files from .c files
%.o: %.c
    $(COMPILE) $< -o $@

# To obtain object files from .s files
%.o: %.s
    $(COMPILE_ASM) $< -o $@

# To remove generated files
clean:
    rm -rf $(EXEC) $(OBJECTS)
```

Comment: *my makefile names the executable as the parent directory* I don't understand this sentence, could you edit and define "naming an executable" ?

Comment: Ok, got it. Where is the makefile located ? In `/home/Daniel/project1` or in the folder containing the file?

Comment: In the folder containing the files, `/home/Daniel/project1/makefile`

Comment: What about adding in the link recipe (after the link command) `mv main $(EXEC)` . Doesn't that to the trick?

Comment: Can you explain please

Comment: Well, the main target will produce from file `main.c` the file `main.o` that gets linked into the executable `main` (`main.exe` on Windows, but I understand you are using Linux). So all you need to do (if I understand correctly the problem) is to rename the file using the `EXEC` variable that holds the folder name.

Comment: The problem is I dont know what file `int main()` will be in. It can be in `main.c` but it can also be in `random_file_1337.c`

Comment: Oh... Well that wasn't clear in the question... |-(

Comment: Something still unclear to me: at present, your makefile does exactly what you want: the link step links together the object files into an executable file, named with the var `$(EXEC)`... which holds the folder name! So, what ?